# Return func or func() in decorators

Tags: python

I am learning decorators following "fluent python" with the following example:

```
registry = []

def register(func):
    print("running register(%s)" % func)
    registry.append(func)
    return func

@register
def f1():
    print("runnning f1()")

@register
def f2():
    print("running f2()")

def f3():
    print("running f3()")

def main():
    print("running main()")
    print("registry ->", registry)
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ran it and come by:

```
running register(<function f1 at 0x10870ab70>)
running register(<function f2 at 0x1086f58c8>)
running main()
registry -> [<function f1 at 0x10870ab70>, <function f2 at 0x1086f58c8>]
runnning f1()
running f2()
running f3()
```

Then I changed the register's returned result from `return func` to return `func()`

```
def register(func):
    print("running register(%s)" % func)
    registry.append(func)
    return func()
```

Ran it and get

```
running register(<function f1 at 0x108753d08>)
runnning f1()
running register(<function f2 at 0x108753488>)
running f2()
running main()
registry -> [<function f1 at 0x108753d08>, <function f2 at 0x108753488>]
```

I cannot definitely figure out the difference.

Comment: You should have also gotten an error message.

Comment: `return func` returns the function object, `return func()` *calls* `func` then returns whatever `func` returned.

Comment: Your code will obviously raise a `TypeError; 'NoneType object is not callable` if you replace `return func` by `return func()`, o whatever you "ran" after this modification is not what you think.